# Drupal Display Format

Tags: drupal-7

I need to change the Display Format of a view to use a module. I can not find where to change the Display Format. Does anyone know where to do this?

Answer (score 0):

On the settings for the view, `/admin/structure/views/view/view_name/edit`, there is a fieldset titled "FORMAT" right beneath the "TITLE" setting. The first option in that fieldset is the format option. You can display view results as a grid, an HTML-formmated list (ul, ol), a table, an unformatted list (series of divs) or a jump menu. Each format has its own settings as well.